# How to show entered order no and selected product name and id

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am new in mvc. so could not figure out what to add in code to show entered order no and selected product name and id.

here is full code and `dotnetfiddle url https://dotnetfiddle.net/6vn2GO`

### Model code

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class OrderViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Order number")]
        public int? OrderNumber { set; get; }
        [Display(Name = "Product")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a product")]
        public int SelectedProductId { set; get;}
        public SelectList ProductList { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public int ID { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
    }

    public static class Repository
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Product> FetchProducts()
        {
            return new List<Product>()
            {
                new Product(){ ID = 1, Name = "Ketchup" },
                new Product(){ ID = 2, Name = "Mustard" },
                new Product(){ ID = 3, Name = "Relish" }
            };
        }
    }

}
```

### Controller code

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            OrderViewModel model = new OrderViewModel();
            model.OrderNumber=null;
            ConfigureViewModel(model);
            return View(model);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(OrderViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ConfigureViewModel(model);
                return View(model);
            }
            // save and redirect
            // but for testing purposes
            ConfigureViewModel(model);
            return View(model);
        }

        private void ConfigureViewModel(OrderViewModel model)
        {
            IEnumerable<Product> products = Repository.FetchProducts();
            model.ProductList = new SelectList(products, "ID", "Name");
        }
    }
}
```

### View.cshtml code

```
@model HelloWorldMvcApp.OrderViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- template from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started -->

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

        <!-- CSS Includes -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <style type="text/css">

            .field-validation-error {
                color: #ff0000;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1>Hello Stranger</h1>
                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrderNumber)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrderNumber, new {@class="form-control"}) 
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OrderNumber)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedProductId)
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedProductId, Model.ProductList, "-Please select-", new {@class="form-control"}) 
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedProductId)
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit">Save</button>
                }
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- JS includes -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

please tell me what code i need to add in view html to show entered order no and selected product name and id. thanks

Comment: Where do you want to show it?

Comment: in the same view. first form would appear and when form submit and if all inputs will be valid then form should not show rather entered input in form will be selected like order no, selected product id and name.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the value of your order number on the [HttpPost] Action method and check if it's null on the view side and show/hide stuff accordingly.

Another (probably better) alternative would be to just create a new view and return that when the model state is valid.  To get the order number, you'll need to fetch the inserted ID from the database and pass that to the view.

Edit to show some code:

Controller Code:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            OrderViewModel model = new OrderViewModel();
            model.OrderNumber=null;
            ConfigureViewModel(model);
            return View(model);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(OrderViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ConfigureViewModel(model);
                return View(model);
            }
            // save and redirect
            // but for testing purposes
            ConfigureViewModel(model);
            // you'll need to figure out how you're generating your
            // order numbers
            // 
            model.OrderNumber = 1; // just set this statically for now for POC
            return View(model);
        }

        private void ConfigureViewModel(OrderViewModel model)
        {
            IEnumerable<Product> products = Repository.FetchProducts();
            model.ProductList = new SelectList(products, "ID", "Name");
        }
    }
}
```

View Code:

```
@model HelloWorldMvcApp.OrderViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- template from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started -->

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

        <!-- CSS Includes -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <style type="text/css">

            .field-validation-error {
                color: #ff0000;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
         @{
          if(Model.OrderNumber == null)
          {
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1>Hello Stranger</h1>
                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrderNumber)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrderNumber, new {@class="form-control"}) 
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OrderNumber)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedProductId)
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedProductId, Model.ProductList, "-Please select-", new {@class="form-control"}) 
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedProductId)
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit">Save</button>
                }
            </div>
            } else {
            <div>show your confirmation stuff here</div>
            }
         }

        </div>

        <!-- JS includes -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

that will reuse the same view, though as I said, I'd recommend using a different view.

Comment: then what are you using to generate the order number?

Comment: the code you gave is not helpful for me. i asked how to show selected data after form post. after form post how could i show order no, selected product id and name in same view. if u know how to do it then please provide code. thanks